# How to calculate work done in climbing? Why is the force always the same as the weight?? Why?

Tags: work

I know by definition the work is simply equal to weight times displacement in meter.

But say 1 g is needed to stay still against the force of gravity, the weight. Then to move up you need more force, don't ya?

So then why is it just the weight times displacement? Isn't this simply the force needed to stay still?

This is how I think of this in terms of elementary physics:
Staying still means there is no net force. So the two forces cancel each other, Gravity and the force the climber exert on the rope. To climbs up extra force is needed. So there is a net force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes when you want to climb up you need to exert more force up than the gravity down if you are starting from rest.

If we consider a body at rest that then exerts a force upwards greater than gravity it starts to move upwards and so the energy used by the body to move upwards is greater than just the height it moves multiplied by the force of gravity downwards - so why is the work done greater than the increase in gravitational potential energy....?

.... the answer is that when you start from rest and want to move up you need to use energy for two things

1) you need to provide energy to increase the gravitational potential energy of the body
2) you need to provide kinetic energy for your body to move.

Now if you are moving upwards at a constant speed then there will be no net force on you and the energy expended by the body will go into increasing the gravitational potential energy completely and the kinetic energy remains constant.

Hope this helps

Comment: Is kinetic energy part of work done?

Comment: Is gravitational potential energy the weight of the body?

Comment: Of course, you are glossing over the largest energy expenditure -- the energy required to maintain the necessary body posture while climbing.

Comment: @Doeser - work done is the energy used to 'do something' - generally where the energy can be converted to another form. So for example, when a ball is lifted up work is done to lift it up against the pull of gravity - it gains gravitational potential energy. If the ball is dropped then the gravitational potential energy is converted into kinetic energy as it falls and speeds up. .... so the work done is the total energy generated by the body and part  of that energy is turned into kinetic energy - the kinetic energy is the energy of the body moving.

Comment: @Doeser weight of the body is a force - the gravitational force of that pulls down on the boyd - gratitational potential energy is the energy a body gains as it is lifted up. gravitational potential energy can be converted into kinetic energy as in the case of the ball in the last comment. But notice the weight of the ball will be the same if it is held one metre above the ground and if it is held ten metres above the ground, but the gravitational poential energy will be higher in the case where it is ten metres above the ground. Maybe ask new question about difference between force and energy

Comment: @HotLicks - I ignore the energy used by the body to maintain posture because the work done in the physics sense of work done is zero if the body remains still and does not go up or down from the point of view of simple mechanics. Simple mechanics does explain, however, why the up force needs to be greater than the weight to raise the body.

Comment: Well, the OP flip-flopped a bit, but it seemed that he wanted to know the actual total amount of energy expended in climbing.

Comment: Tom, this is what I was taught in school. The only time there can be constant velocity when force is exerted is when there is a contracting force, like friction. Forces being cancel = no net force. But when you are climbing I don't see any of such forces like friction except in your joins.

Comment: @Doeser - if the climber is going up then gravity is the force which is pulling in the opposite direction to the force the climber is exerting. Does that make sense.